# How to solve the key variable on $unset key

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined-index

I am running a PHP script, and keep getting errors like:

> Notice: Undefined variable: key in D:\0-MYBLOG\SERVER-MYBLOG\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sama-author-review\admin\metabox.php on line 310

Line 310 looks like this:

```
unset( $new['items_review'][$key] );
```

Here the code:

```
        if ( $new['items_review'] && is_array( $new['items_review'] )) {

            foreach ( $new['items_review'] as $review ) {

                if ( empty( $review['label'] ) ) {
                    unset( $new['items_review'][$key] );
                } else {
                    $review['value'] = absint( $review['value'] );
                    $review['label'] = esc_attr( $review['label'] );

                    if ( empty( $review['slug'] )) {
                        $review['slug']  = sanitize_title( $review['label'] );
                    } else {
                        $review['slug']  = sanitize_title( $review['slug'] );
                    }
                    $review['style'] = esc_attr( $review['style'] );
                    $items_review[$i] = $review;
                    $i++;
                }
            }   
        }
```

Is there a quick fix to resolve these error?
Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index < possible duplicate of.

Comment: Little different with this unset. I read that post before and can not resolve my problem.

Comment: doubt it. you didn't show anything for `$key` just one line of code.

Comment: `$key` doesn't exist / doesn't have a value and therefore it doesn't know what to unset.

Comment: hello, Matt. Just update, added the code on above. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get what the problem is, you have forgotten to put the key parameter on your `foreach` statement.

I admit its a bit of a guess as I have no idea what is in `$new` but it seams a logical possibility.

```
if ( $new['items_review'] && is_array( $new['items_review'] )) {

//    foreach ( $new['items_review'] as $review ) {
// replace foreach with this line

    foreach ( $new['items_review'] as $key => $review ) {

        if ( empty( $review['label'] ) ) {
            unset( $new['items_review'][$key] );
        } else {
            $review['value'] = absint( $review['value'] );
            $review['label'] = esc_attr( $review['label'] );
            if ( empty( $review['slug'] )) {
                $review['slug']  = sanitize_title( $review['label'] );
            } else {
                $review['slug']  = sanitize_title( $review['slug'] );
            }
            $review['style'] = esc_attr( $review['style'] );
            $items_review[$i] = $review;
            $i++;
        }
    }   
}
```